# Parse Multiple Tables in Wiki Page

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

Currently I'm trying to parse all the tables on this wiki page. However as you can tell by my code, I only retrieve back one table. I'm looking to grab all tables and put them in their appropriate columns/rows.

Below is my code, I'm a bit lost as to what I need to do next.

```
import csv
import urllib 
import requests
import codecs
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = \
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_shootings_in_the_United_States'

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

#remove references Brackets
removeBrackets = re.sub(r'\[.*\]', '', html)
#remove Trailing 0's in numbers
removeTrails = removeBrackets.replace('0,000,001','')

soup = BeautifulSoup(removeTrails)

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'sortable wikitable'})

# remove all extra tags in the HTML Tables
for div in soup.findAll('span', 'sortkey'):
    div.extract();
for div in soup.findAll('span', 'sorttext'):
    div.extract();

#scan through table
list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
#write 
outfile = open("schoolshootings.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow([s.encode('utf8') if type(s) is unicode else s for s in row]) 
writer.writerow(["Date", "Location", "Deaths", "Injuries", "Description"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `findAll` for the tables also instead of a `find`.  If you change this line

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'sortable wikitable'})
```

to:

```
for table in soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'sortable wikitable'}):
```

and indent all the lines down to `list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)` an extra 4 spaces, it will get all the other tables.  You also will need to move `list_of_rows = []` to befor the `.findAll`.

**Edited to Add**

You have a bunch of regex that you really don't need, since it is easier to use `.text`.  Also when you extract the `span` with `sorttext` you remove the Date field which you don't want.  Since I removed the regex, I also needed to extract the `span` with `display:none`

The below code does what you need:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_shootings_in_the_United_States'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

list_of_rows = []
for table in soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'sortable wikitable'}):

    # remove all extra tags in the HTML Tables
    for div in soup.findAll('span', 'sortkey'):
        div.extract();
    for div in soup.findAll('span', {'style':'display:none'}):
        div.extract();

    #scan through table
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
            list_of_cells.append(cell.text)
        list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
```